# xamarin unable to connect to mac - login failure

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

i have a mac mini. i am trying to add this to visual studio (version 2015 with update 3).  it detects mac, gets the SSH fingerprint, and gives me the login screen. but then i get login failure.  i can login through SSH to it without any problem. i can use VNC and connect to it using the same credentials. but i consistently get login failure when trying to connect through xamarin dialog box.

i haven't installed anything on mac, i have only enabled remote login, and enabled all options to connect me to it using SSH and everything seems to be working fine.

i don't understand what i am missing.  i'll appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to install Xamarin Studio for Mac.

Comment: Thanks.  i have starting the installation of Xamarin Studio on my mac.  i saw the logs and it showed that there is no mono on mac, so i was suspecting that something is missing.  i did not realize that it will be required just to add mac.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Xamarin.iOS on your Mac as a minimum to be able to connect from Visual Studio - if you don't have the Xamarin tooling installed on your Mac along with Xcode then you cannot build your iOS apps.

You do not need Xamarin Studio installed on the Mac, just Xamarin.iOS, but it is advisable as it makes it easier to update.

Check out our installation guide which walks you through downloading and installing everything you need:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/mac/

We also have some guides for the Visual Studio side of things which may help if you continue have issues connecting:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/